# Edit and use local HTML file on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, forms, xss

I need to test our web service while I walk several hundred meters back and forth across the factory looking how the machinery responds.

I can do it from my work-laptop, but it weighs approximately 3 kilograms so that my hands get tired after several hours.

The idea is to develop a quick HTML+JS form and submit it from some browser on a mobile device. That would be easily possible from, say, Opera browser on Android, but my work cellphone is an iPhone, and iPhones are known to be restrictive when the user wants to access his own local data.

The tasks I would like to do are:

- to create a local HTML+JS document without having to organize some web server for it
- to open this document easily in a local web browser
- to be able to run JavaScript embedded into this page (some browsers prevent execution of JavaScript in local documents)
- to be able to post with XHR without triggering cross-site posting restriction.
- to be able to make quick edits of this page as needed

Can I do this with iPhone?

I could, but I wouldn't like to add this test page to the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way to get a device like an iPhone to access files on another machine and run them in a browser would be to:

- Run a local webserver ([MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/) on a Mac is easy to install & set up, or maybe Node on any system)
- If it's just an HTML file that contains everything you need, perhaps you could store it somewhere like a shared file server, dropbox, etc.  I think you could then use the app or Safari to access it and run it. It just depends but it might be worth trying out.

Comment: I didn't write about "another" machine. I wrote about iPhone itself. Only HTTP requests to another machine should be sent. I consider HTTP files on another machine as an exceptional case.

Comment: Oh interesting, I understand you now.  So... well no I don't think what you want is really possible since you can't just store files on an iPhone.  However, using a service like Dropbox or iCloud Files might work for your purposes.  The file is stored there, and within those apps you can probably view those files, hopefully view a rendered view of those files in a browser.  I'm not 100% sure but you should give something like that a try.